# Echo specific phrases later in the text

Tags: cross-referencing

I am writing a college course outline. It contains both a table with an overview of the dates and topics and a more extended outline of the specific topics later in the text. Ideally, I would like to input the dates into the table and have other places in the text echo the dates, so I don't have to make the changes in multiple places. I'm sure this is possible, I just don't know how.

Comment: If you say `\def\dateColumbus{1492}`, then wherever in the document you use `\dateColumbus{}`, the text `1492` will appear.

Answer (score 1):

Using `xparse`, you could do something like this. Note that this uses the new and experimental(but stable) syntax from the LaTeX3-team. It is meant for class- and package-developers, so it follows a very different syntax than LaTeX and TeX. The same code could ofcourse be made in TeX also.

Here, you get info by writing `\vars{name}`, where `name` would produce your name.

You could of course use just a regular `\newcommand{\myname}{John Doe}` and you would have a variable by calling `\myname`. It depends on what kind of syntax you want.

#### Output

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\vars}{m}
 {
    \str_case_x:nn {\str_foldcase:n {#1}}
     {
      {name}{John\ Doe}
      {phone}{555\,12345}
      {mytable}{%
        \begin{tabular}{lr}
          \hline
          Foo & Bar \\
          \hline
          \vars{name} & \vars{phone}\\
          \hline
        \end{tabular}
        }
     }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

My name is \vars{name}.

\begin{table}[hbt]
  \centering
  \caption{My info}
  \vars{mytable}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```